# Define all external JavaScript in a pre-existing namespace

Tags: javascript

**I am fully aware of the dangers of eval and such, so please don't waste your time commenting on how these hacks are hacks.**

Say I'm using a third-party JavaScript library, but I'd like all of it's code to be defined within a particular namespace... that I also don't control. For example:

```
<script src="http://example.com/library.js>
<!-- library.js contains:
     var x = 0;
     function foo() {}
-->
```

I'd like to be able to define `x` and `foo` in the context of, say, namespace `Bar`, instead of the global context (`window`).

Assuming `Bar` is defined, but in another external js file that I don't control, I have tried some hacks, for example:

```
<script>
var externalCode = $.ajax("http://example.com/library.js");
eval.call(Bar, externalCode);
// and also tried:  
(function(str){ eval(str); }).call(Bar, externalCode);
</script>
```

But I am not able to access `Bar.x` nor invoke `Bar.foo()`.

Basically, I want to achieve the results I would get if I pasted the contents of *library.js* inside my `Bar` namespace, a la:

```
var Bar = {
    x: 0,
    foo: function() {}
  }
```

However, I am trying to do this when I also lack control over the `Bar` namespace. Hence I can't "copy and paste." Another related example is how we can "punch in" new methods into pre-existing class definitions in Ruby.

Lastly, my specific use case is that I'm trying to "inject" everything from *p5.js* into the `Opal` namespace.

Comment: Ouch! Don't use eval (ever!) and use .bind() instead of call or apply.

Comment: @ybakos Not everyone knows about eval and call/apply. In fact, most don't. You may know about them and good for you, but don't chastise us for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution that works in browsers today is:

```
<script src="http://example.com/library.js>
<!-- library.js contains:
 var x = 0;
 function foo() {}
-->
<script>
$.ajax('/library.js', function(jsString) {
    var wrapped  = `function() { 
       ${jsString};
       Bar.x = x;
       Bar.foo = foo;
    }();`
    eval(wrapped);
});
</script>
```

However, a solution that doesn't require listing modules is [EcmaScript 6 modules](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html). If you transpile it with https://babeljs.io/, it can work with today's browsers.

```
//------ main.js ------
import * as Bar from 'lib';
console.log(Bar.foo()); // no error
console.log(Bar.x); // 0
```

If you need it to work in all browsers today, and don't want to transpile your code, you'd need the first example, which could be generalized as

```
function importIntoNs(ns, scriptUrl, symbolNames) {
  $.ajax(scriptUrl, function(jsString) {
    var wrapped = `(function() { 
       ${jsString};`;
    symbolNames.forEach(symbolName => {
        wrapped += 'this.' + symbolName + ' = symbolName;\n'  ;       
    }); 
    wrapped += '})';

    eval(wrapped).apply(ns);
  }
}

importIntoNs(Bar, 'http://example.com/library.js', ['x', 'foo']);
```

If anyone wants to downvote because of the eval, remember that the OP is already going to execute the script no matter what if they put it in a `<script>` tag.

Here's a working example without fetching the script.

```js
function importScriptIntoNs(ns, jsString,  symbolNames) {  
  var addSymbols = '';
  symbolNames.forEach(symbolName => {
    addSymbols += 'this.' + symbolName + ' = ' + symbolName + ';\n';
  }); 
  
  var wrapped = `(function() {;
     ${jsString}
     ${addSymbols}
  })`;

  eval(wrapped).apply(ns);
}

var Bar = {};

var jsString = `
   var x = 'It works';
   function foo() {alert(x)}
`;

importScriptIntoNs(Bar, jsString, ['x', 'foo']);

Bar.foo()
```

Comment: Hmm... with the drawback being that I have to explicitly list all identifiers in the `symbolNames` array, right?

Comment: I would not say that's a drawback, you have know the names to be able to call `Bar.foo()` anyway. I call it a feature. It should also help you detect/prevent collisions. Another angle, with any module system, you have specify what to export, this is creating a module around what was previously free standing, global polluting code.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I get it.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You could use EcmaScript 6 modules and transpile it using https://babeljs.io/

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle libraries and other dependencies *without* polluting the global scope is to use some kind of [Asynchronous Module Definition](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD). A good one that I like to use and recommend is [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html).

The whole idea behind it is that you're able to bundle your libraries and dependencies into modules and call on them when you need, without simply loading everything on the global scope.

Here is an example of how you might use it in your situation:

```
require(['http://example.com/library.js'], function(Bar){
    // library.js is now bound within this scope under the alias Bar
});
```

Comment: Note that the library has to support `require`, otherwise, good answer

Comment: @JuanMendes There are ways with Require.js to accommodate for this, which is one of the reasons I like it :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I know require.js, it's an AMD module loader. A module has to be written specifically so it can be `require`d. You can't `require()` any script as the OP would like

Comment: @JuanMendes [Check this out](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html). This is an example of using Require.js with a library like JQuery utilizing shim

Comment: That's because jQuery was made to work with require, it had to be modified. Note the first few lines in https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js

Comment: @JuanMendes Ah I see what you mean now - I was unaware of this, thank you for bringing it to my attention! Interesting, I wonder if there is an efficient way to accommodate for this issue without manually adjusting libraries for `define`

Comment: @JuanMendes I'm pretty sure Require.js has a feature by which global variables can be shimmed, see: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Comment: @NickZuber That's what I was thinking of, you load the JS with AJAX, then insert some code at the end to make it module friendly. It would have to be custom for each script, and would not have to change unless the public API was changed

Comment: Thanks @NickZuber ... I'll look into require.js. Is there any way you could update the code snippet in your answer to reflect the `Bar` namespace I mentioned?

Comment: @NickZuber Didn't like my edit? What you have now is not adding to a namespace...